# Proposed tag synonym: {profiling} and {performance}

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

The tags [profiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/profiling) and [performance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) seem to be pretty similar: the [profiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/profiling) excerpt says

> {profiling} is for questions involving the efficiency/speed of a macro, technique or construct.

which seems to be a subset of what I would understand as "performance".

The current usage seems to draw no clear distinction between these two tags, compare e. g. [Why does it take LuaLaTeX so long to load fonts and can I speed it up?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75118/3323) (tagged [profiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/profiling)) and [unicode-math + siunitx + lualatex = long compile times. Why?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226747/3323) (tagged [performance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance)).

Currently, there are 15 questions tagged [profiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/profiling) and 39 questions tagged [performance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance).

I therefore propose to make [profiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/profiling) a synonym of [performance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance), as  the latter seems to be the more easily understood term to me and is therefore more likely to be found when looking for appropriate question tags.

Comment: Have you gone through the 15 Qs seeing if none of them is mis-tagged?

Comment: @yo' All the 15 questions tagged [tag:profiling] are somehow related to the speed of an operation in LaTeX. About 6 of them seem to ask more generally how to do benchmarks in LaTeX (`\pdfelapsedtime` etc.), with no direct problem given. The others are more along the lines of "How can I make ... faster?" or "Why is ... slower on [operating system]?" or "Will it make a difference if I implement ... differently?", i. e. related to a specific operation. [tag:performance] mainly seems to about questions of the latter category, however there are [exceptions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204/3323).

Comment: Ok thanks. Now I'm all for :-) I just wanted to be sure that group re-tag doesn't cause any harm.

Comment: While you're at it: The [tag:performance] wiki needs love.